# Unity2d; How to raise(lift) camera during game mode at a fixed y axis minimum

Tags: camera, 2d, axis, unity-game-engine

I may be making this harder than what it really is,  but I am also pretty new to developing games.  Currently I am making a practice scene to get back used to the unity engine as I have not had time to  use it since last summer.  My issue is that I can not figure out how to lift the camera in game mode. Notice my photo below, and how much of the "underground" is showing.  I want to raise the camera to keep it at the very least a specific y axis value, so that I can make less of the ground visible, and more of the background visible. If I am over complicating this, please also let me know. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If main camera is still then just lift the camera in scene view you can see changes in game view.

Or if camera moves with respect to player then you have to use a script and attach it to camera and get a reference of player transform in the script and according to the player position change position of the camera. Add an offset value in y component  of the camera.

Comment: Any idea what the code for an offset value in the y axis would be?  This is the exact answer I was looking for, except I have no idea how to do it. Also would I make a new script, or just edit the follow character script?